# Using ffmpeg to convert sound files for use in an android app

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, mp3

**short:** i'm trying to simply play a sound file converted with ffmpeg in my android app, but happen to have problems getting it to work.

**long:** we have an iphone app and an android app doing the same thing, and i have to port the feature playing a sound on an user interaction. i have the source file in the `aiff` format, and tried to convert it to `mp3` for android. but the app keeps crashing when it tries to load the file

```
AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(resid);
final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), fileDescriptor.getStartOffset(), fileDescriptor.getLength());
fileDescriptor.close();
mp.prepare();
```

more specifically, `mp.setDataSource` crashes. some digging around led me to believe that something's wrong with the encoding. the sound file itself resides in res/raw.

```
11-29 17:11:48.012: ERROR/SoundManager(15580): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
11-29 17:11:48.012: ERROR/SoundManager(15580):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
...
```

what i tried:

- using a different mp3 that's already used with the same code in a different place. this works.
- converted it to wav file. this didn't cause the app to crash, but it neither played a sound. that might be a different problem.
- converted it to ogg; crashed

so, the the `ffmpeg` conversion parameters are as follows:

```
$ ffmpeg -i click_24db.aif -f mp3 ~/foobar/wheel_click.mp3
ffmpeg version 0.7.8, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 24 2011 14:31:00 with gcc 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libdirac --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --cc=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 --arch=x86_64 --enable-yasm
  libavutil    50. 43. 0 / 50. 43. 0
  libavcodec   52.123. 0 / 52.123. 0
  libavformat  52.111. 0 / 52.111. 0
  libavdevice  52.  5. 0 / 52.  5. 0
  libavfilter   1. 80. 0 /  1. 80. 0
  libswscale    0. 14. 1 /  0. 14. 1
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
Input #0, aiff, from 'click_24db.aif':
  Duration: 00:00:00.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1570 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: pcm_s16be, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
Output #0, mp3, to '/Users/xyz/foobar/wheel_click.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf52.111.0
    Stream #0.0: Audio: libmp3lame, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=       1kB time=00:00:00.05 bitrate=  92.9kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 45.563549%
```

the resulting file plays nice in itunes, does not play in vlc and crashes when loaded with the android.media.MediaPlayer (note: i first tried it with the SoundPool lib, with both mp3 and ogg, but that didn't work either).

i also tried the following paramters, which didn't work:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.aif -f mp3 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 192000 -ar 44100 outputfile.mp3
```

i'm working on osx, built ffmpeg with macports today, android api level is 7 (google api, 2.1-update1). looking at the "supported formats" table on [dev.android](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) didn't indicate my file to be out of the spec, but i may be mistaken in that.

i don't have the slightest clue regarding bitrates and so on, so could anybody please point me to the right combination of ffmpeg parameters to get a working mp3 for android? i don't care if the resulting file would be mp3, ogg or 3gp or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not what you're looking for, but for audio work you might have better luck with [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/).  It's sort've like ffmpeg just for audio.  Though to my eyes what you've done with ffmpeg should've worked.